# Update form from class or interface

Tags: winforms, class, interface, controls

I have a winform onto which I have a number of controls across a few tabs. I am writing logic which will enable / disable some of these controls based on the combo box selections made by the user. I am guessing that writing the logic in frmMain.vb isn't best practice so I'm wondering whether I should gain access to my form's controls through:

1. an interface
2. through friend-declared properties in frmMain.vb that are accessed by another class or
3. Other

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: if the controls are on the form, and the combo boxes that are meant to hide and show them are also on the form, then why would it be bad practice to show/hide them on the form? Unless you are dealing with  business logic that is being retrieved without user input that then displays or hides controls, there is no need to further complicate your code by moving it from the form where the controls reside to another class or library. The only other instance I can think of where you would want to move the show/hide code to a new class would be if that class was making the controls on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is a good idea to tie your front-end code to a buisiness logic layer so that it is the logic that controls the enabling/disabling of the controls. If possible, group the controls based on what will get disabled together, then make a routine that disables them all at once, and name it well, like `disableAddContactInfoArea()` or `SetAddContactInfoArea(boolean isEnabled)`. In my mind, the routine will sit in `frmMain.vb`.
One thing to avoid is just exposing each individual control to another class (unless, in ine case, that is all you need for a specific business process - but even then you should put it in a routine and name it well to make future edits easy and less complex). Your primary objective is to manage complexity (check out Steve McConnell's book [Code complete](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/cc.htm), maybe chapter 7 for this).

An ideal would be to have a few `public Sub`s on the `frmMain.vb`, only there to do exactly what needs done, then have the business logic layer call those routines on the instace of `frmMain` that you are using.